# PHP user profile picture cache

Tags: php, image, caching

Okay, so on my website a user can upload a profile picture. But the issue is, if they update it by uploading and overwriting the existing profile picture they have to wait for their browser cache to clear and the same for everyone else on the site.

I know I could easily beat this by sticking a string on the end of the image URL e.g. `?id=22185` , but that will make my site loading times VERY slow.

Could any of you recommend a way of making the user's profile picture update instantly for every user on the site?

Comment: Use the updated timestamp at as the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the file modified time as the URL variable.  That way the image will be cached until that number changes, which only would happen of the file is updated.

Comment: so instead of <img src = "..../user_image.jpg"/> I would do <img src = "..../user_image.jpg?time=1344194473"/>

Comment: Yep!  That's how many sites prevent caching of images, Js, CSS, etc.

Comment: Where would I store the update time, in a database table? If so surely that would kill my server having to run a sql query to get the update timestamp to put on the end of the URL.

Comment: Use php to get the modified time of the file.  If you do store data about the image in the database, then just add a column for modified date and retrieve that column when you get the other data for the image.  The former is how I would do it unless you can't because images are not accessible with php's file functions.

Answer (score 1):

Set unique name for each image. When user change image, e filename change too and browser will load new image instead of serving old FROM cache

Answer (score 0):

You could easily add a timestamp to your files or you could use the "headers" function of PHP to change the "Expire" param.